# How to convert arraylist to tuple?

Tags: python, apache-spark

```
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Data of type java.util.ArrayList cannot be used
```

My rdd was made from an avro file that contains a key "mylist". How do I change this such that it uses a tuple of tuples instead? Is there a way to create a new RDD but convert that current arraylist of maps to a tuple of tuple of maps instead of arraylist of maps?

i.e. instead of `[{"a":"vala", "a1":"vala1"},{"b":"valb", "b1":"valb1"}]`, change it to `(({"a":"vala", "a1":"vala1"},{"b":"valb","b1":"valb1"}))`

Comment: Could clarify what you mean by "tuple of tuples"? Your example shows a tuple of dicts.

Comment: My mistake, I meant tuple of tuple of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to call `tuple` on your list:

```
>>> tuple([{"a":"vala", "a1":"vala1"},{"b":"valb", "b1":"valb1"}])
({'a': 'vala', 'a1': 'vala1'}, {'b1': 'valb1', 'b': 'valb'})
```

Comment: This is great, but how do I create a new RDD from it for the specific field?